# gcovr not generating coverage files from remote location

Tags: jenkins, xcode4.5, code-coverage, jenkins-plugins, gcov

When I execute the gcovr file from within my folder containing the .gcno & .gcda files, the coverage.xml file is being generated.

Folder Location -
/Users//….. /x86_64/

Gcovr Location -
/Users//….. /x86_64/gcovr

Current Location -
/Users//….. /x86_64/

Command -
python gcovr –x > coverage.xml

The coverage files contains the code coverage report.

BUT, if I call the same executable from a remote location 
Ex.

Current Location -
/Users/

Gcovr Location -
/Users//….. /x86_64/gcovr

Command -
python /Users//….. /x86_64/gcovr –r /Users//….. /x86_64/ –x > coverage.xml

Also, same is the case when I have gcovr on a remote location and call it for the root folder of my coverage files.

Current Location -
/Users/

Gcovr Location -
/Users//gcovr

Command -
python /Users//gcovr –r /Users//….. /x86_64/ –x > coverage.xml

The coverage file does not contain the coverage report. It looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage
  SYSTEM 'http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-03.dtd'>
<coverage branch-rate="0.0" line-rate="0.0" timestamp="1365619556" version="gcovr 2.5-      prerelease (r2823)">
    <sources>
        <source>
            /Users/<username>/….. /x86_64/<Code Coverage Files>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <packages/>
</coverage>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at my gcovr lines, which work both on master and slave, I'm always executing from the build directory and pointing at the coverage/object directory in the command line.   This seemed to be necessary for the source lines to be found.   That might be worth a try

Comment: @gaige: You might want to add this as an answer, since this helped me too!

Comment: @asgoth I have done so.  Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at my gcovr lines, which work both on master and slave, I'm always executing from the build directory and pointing at the coverage/object directory in the command line. This seemed to be necessary for the source lines to be found.

Answer (score 0):

May be this question will help you resolve the issue.

[GCOVR giving empty results zero percent in MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875615/gcovr-giving-empty-results-zero-percent-in-mac/38917149)

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile with following option? : `-ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs`

Did you link with following option? : `-fprofile-arcs`

Here my way of excluding superfluous files:

```
gcovr --xml -e ".*unit-test.*\.cpp" -e ".*unit-test.*\.h" -e ".*usr/include/.*" -e ".*jenkins.*" -o coverage.xml
```

Remote files are always found correct, although I cannot open them from Jenkins.